# container not able to access host service if "network_mode: host" used

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-container

I have defined 2 containers in my docker-compose.yml.
Container 1 communicates with the service running on host machine via HTTP requests.
Container 2 needs to access the internet, hence network_mode:host is set, so that it can access the host interface (eth0 and eth1).

docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  container1:
    image: Image1
    environment:
      - SYSTEMAPI_URI
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TTY_CONFIG
    devices:
      - "/dev/tty1:/dev/tty1"
      - "/dev/tty2:/dev/tty2"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/<>
  container2:
    image: Image2
    environment:
      - SYSTEMAPI_URI
      - STORAGE_FOLDER=/mnt
      - CERTIFICATE_PATH=/mnt/cert
      - STORAGE_HOST=/var/lib/docker/volumes/<>
      - EXTRA_CONFIG=${DOLLAR}SYSTEMAPI_VAR_DNSMASQ_EXTRA_CONFIG
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/<>
    privileged: true
    network_mode: "host"
```

With network_mode set to host, HTTP requests from container1 to the host service are failing with timeout. The route command has entries only for eth0 and eth1.
Without network_mode, the requests passes but container2 looses connectivity to internet.

Is network_mode used the correct way here? If not, can somebody tell how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to get access to services running on host is to add `extra_hosts` (here is the official [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)). You also don't need the privileged mode (it is usually better to avoid it whenever possible).

With extra_hosts you map the name that your container is looking for to the IP of your host.